# Ctrl + L will not work as my commenting shortcut

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

It wont work for both commenting lines and commenting blocks of lines. All other shortcuts work. the ctrl and the / keys work as well. My android studio does have them setup on the shortcuts settings as seen in the following [image]

The shortcut will not work on either the laptop's keyboard nor on my bluetooth keyboard (logitech k360).
Laptop is running windows 10. If any body can shed some light on anything I could try to get my shortcuts back I would appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a number of things but the one that worked was invalidating the cache and restarting android studio by going to File -> Invalidate caches / Restart...